# What is a good server-side RSS feed aggregator I can integrate in my website?

Tags: java, rss

I am looking at options for adding a relevant "news" section to a community site I am building.  One option I'm considering is aggregating news from a variety of RSS feeds, and showing the top headlines on the home page, as well as specific headlines on more focused content pages.

Rather than reinventing the wheel, it really seems like I should be able to find a reasonable solution that already exists.  My ideal checklist for an aggregator:

- Can process multiple feeds
- Stores news items in MySQL database, so my website can just read the news items from the database
- Runs in background, constantly updating new items
- Plays nice (respects caching, can set refresh interval, etc.)
- Nice to have: ability to tag or query stored news items based on keywords
- Bonus if it's in Java

I found a few options so far:

http://rnews.sourceforge.net/

http://code.google.com/p/rsslounge/

http://feedonfeeds.com/

But they're all PHP, and have a lot of extra stuff (a full-blown web UI, user management, etc.) that I don't need.

What other options should I look at?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [Rome](http://java.net/projects/rome/)

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use the Rome RSS/Atom libraries, [this tutorial page](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Rss+and+atOM+utilitiEs+%28ROME%29+v0.5+Tutorial,+Using+ROME+to+aggregate+many+syndication+feeds+into+a+single+one) describes how to implement a feed aggregator.

Note that Rome doesn't provide a feed aggregator *per se*.  You'd have to implement all of the higher level functions / requirements yourself.